# Wireless Internet connection not available in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, wireless-networking, laptop, battery

My laptop brand is ASUS, a few days ago the wireless connection was still working.

This morning I pressed the power button and it did not start.

I tried to take out the battery (my laptop is 2 years old) and start it up. When the Windows 8 logo showed, I put the battery back. After this, everything works fine, except the network connection icon shows a mini desktop screen with an 'x' beside it.

I now have to use a wired connection. It has happened many times and somehow I've managed to fix this, but the problem comes back once I take out the battery to start my laptop.

I have checked Windows Update, but just no update available for my driver.

---

### Update

My laptop came with Wireless Console 3 pre-installed and it relies on it, so the Fn+F2 switch won't work when WC3 is not running.

Answer (score 1):

Most laptops have a physical switch or a fn+fx key combination to switch the wireless adapter off and on. Have you checked to make sure it hasn't been switched off by accident?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that my laptop came Wireless Console 3 preinstalled and it relies on it, so the Fn+F2 switch won't work when WC3 is not running.